# Непонятные сбои в консольной программе

Tags: c++, типы-данных

Дана задача: В населеном пункте проживает N человек, о каждом известно фамилия, возвраст и пол. Ввести информацию о жителях данного пункта и посчитать количество женщин и мужчин. Вывести информацию о среднем возврасте мужчин и женщин. Вывести фамилии тех мужчин/женщин, чей возвраст выше/ниже среднего.

Обязательно использовать структуру.

После ввода Фамилии происходит такая проблема:
[image: Неважно ввожу я фамилию как на скрине или нормально по русски]

ПОЯСНЕНИЯ К КОДУ:
ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ f-количество женщин    m-количество мужчин     age_m-средний возвраст мужчин     age_f-средний возвраст женщин

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Vilage
{
    char gen;
    char sename;
    int age;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int i, f = 0, m = 0;
    double age_m = 0, age_f = 0;
    Vilage N[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "Введите Пол проживающего (m-мужчина, f-женщина): " << endl;
        cin>>N[i].gen;
        cout << "Введите Фамилию проживающего: " << endl;
        cin >> N[i].sename;
        cout << "Введите Возвраст проживающего: " << endl;
        cin >> N[i].age;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (N[i].gen == 'm') {
            m++;
            age_m += N[i].age;
        }
        if (N[i].gen == 'f') {
            f++;
            age_f += N[i].age;
        }
    }
    age_m /= m;
    age_f /= f;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Средний возвраст мужчин составляет: " << age_m << " лет" << endl;
    cout << "Фамилии мужчин, чей возвраст выше среднего: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (N[i].gen == 'm') {
            if (N[i].age > age_m)
                cout << N[i].sename;
        }
    }
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Средний возвраст женщин составляет: " << age_f << " лет" << endl;
    cout << "Фамилии женщин, чей возвраст ниже среднего: " << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (N[i].gen == 'm') {
            if (N[i].age < age_m)
                cout << N[i].sename;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char sename;` кхе-кхе. 1 символ фамилия?)

Comment: Что за белиберда? Скриншот показывает "Введите колличество..." (sic). В коде ничего подобного вообще нет. Зачем вы привели фейковый код?

Comment: AnT, ого целая строка кода пропала, "DANGER: фейк код!!! повторяю, фейк код!!!!! проходите мимо!!!! в выводе есть вывод цеолого сообщения которого нет в коде!!!! фейк код!!!!!". Ну удалили я эту ненужную строку забыл поменять скрин, вот это повод для report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char sename;
```

и

```
    cout << "Введите Фамилию проживающего: " << endl;
    cin >> N[i].sename;
```

Вы считываете 1 (прописью: *один*) символ в `sename`, а все остальное из `Petrov` пытаетесь считать в `int age`. А так как это не число - понятно, что получается одна большая ошибка - вы же "защиту от дурака" (от неверного ввода) не писали...

Comment: Спасибо, понял ошибку, все теперь работает.

"защиту от дурака" написать не проблема, просто это у меня идет как практическая работа в колледже, и получается что весь код должен быть в тетради, и так писать не мало.